# Flattern Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

I have been messing around with this for some days now, and I can't wrap my head around it:

I have the following structure:

```
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>
```

Containing the following data:

```
P1     S1, S2
P2     S1, S2
```

Where the P-prefixed values are dictionary keys and S-prefixed values are the HashSet values.

What I need is the following output List,

```
P1, P2, S1, S2
```

In the case I would have the following startvalues :

```
P1     S1, S2
P2     S1
```

The output List should be :

```
P1, P2, S1, P1, S2
```

If there similar values in the HashSet of several dictionary items, it should group them together, that's why P1, P2, have S1, P1 has only S2

Here's a little TestApp that clarifies more:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var start = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
    var output = new List<string>();

    //example1
    start.Add("P1", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2" });
    start.Add("P2", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2" });
    output = HocusPocus(start);
    PrintResult(output); // should be P1, P2, S1, S2

    //example 2
    start.Clear();
    start.Add("P1", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2" });
    start.Add("P2", new HashSet<string> { "S1" });
    output = HocusPocus(start);
    PrintResult(output); // should be P1, P2, S1, P1, S2

    //example 3
    start.Clear();
    start.Add("P1", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2", "S3" });
    start.Add("P2", new HashSet<string> { "S1" });
    start.Add("P3", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2" });
    output = HocusPocus(start);
    PrintResult(output); // should be P1, P2, P3, S1, P1, P3, S2, P1, S3

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static List<string> HocusPocus(Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> data)
{
    // magic happens here
}

public static void PrintResult(List<string> result)
{
    result.ForEach(x => Console.Write($"{x},"));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit what you actually want to happen?  I could try and guess from your output but its not really clear.  What are P and S?

Comment: When you create a hash set of strings you usually merge using a character not part of normal data like "P1^P2^S1^P1^S2".

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Why should we do your work? It´s nt that hard to build a loop that iterates your dictionary and putrs the values into a flattended list. Anyway should the output be `P1, P2, S1, S2` or `P1, P2, S1, P1, S2`.

Comment: Of course i tried several things already, like loops, and stuff, but that only gets me so far.  It's a combination of gathering the dictionary keys, comparing the HashSet values, Intersect them, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of [Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452433/358221) that walks the primary dictionary once to build the inverted dictionary, and uses sets instead of sequences (it also works inside your original method signatures):

```
public static List<string> HocusPocus(Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> data)
{
    var invert = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

    foreach (var kvp in data)
    {
        foreach (var s in kvp.Value)
        {
            if (!invert.TryGetValue(s, out var pvalues))
            {
                pvalues = new HashSet<string>();
                invert[s] = pvalues;
            }

            pvalues.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
    }

    var lookup = invert
        .ToLookup(_ => _.Value, _ => _.Key, new SetComparer());

    var flat = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in lookup)
    {
        flat.AddRange(item.Key);
        flat.AddRange(item);
    }

    return flat;
}


public class SetComparer : IEqualityComparer<ISet<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(ISet<string> x, ISet<string> y)
    {
        return x.SetEquals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ISet<string> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            foreach (var foo in obj)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + foo.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution has better performance as it doesn't require a separate pass to collect the S values.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you for each S want to find all the P's that are associated with that S and furthermore group S values with the same set of P values. If you dataset isn't to big you can do that quite simply if not in the most efficient way.

Your data:

```
var start = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> {
    { "P1", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2", "S3" } },
    { "P2", new HashSet<string> { "S1" } },
    { "P3", new HashSet<string> { "S1", "S2" } }
};
```

First all the S values are needed for the next iteration:

```
var allSValues = start.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).Distinct();
```

To be able to group by sequences of P values an `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>` is required:

```
class SequenceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>
{
    // Does not handle null values correctly.
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<string> x, IEnumerable<string> y) => x.SequenceEqual(y);

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<string> obj)
    {
        unchecked {
            return obj.Aggregate(17, (hash, @string) => hash * 23*@string.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

(The comparison should treat the input as sets, not sequences, but for this purpose the ordering is stable so it will work.)

The P values for each S value is found and this is then grouped into a lookup which is like a dictionary except there can be multiple values (S values) for each key (sequence of P values):

```
var lookup = allSValues.Select(s => new
    {
        S = s,
        PValues = start
            .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(s))
            .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToLookup(item => item.PValues, item => item.S, new SequenceEqualityComparer());
```

You can print the lookup:

```
foreach (var items in lookup)
{
    Console.Write(string.Join(" ", items.Key));
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", items));
}
```

Comment: This is awesome !
Your code works for example 2 and 3, but not really for example1, it returns P1,P2,S1,P1,P2,S2 where I expected P1, P2, S1, S2 - but maybe I can fix that

Comment: @MichaelBruyninckx Might be awesome, but it doesn't do what you imply with your expected output... for that you need to identify the S values that share P values and union them together.

Comment: @MichaelBruyninckx: You and Adam are correct that I overlooked one important aspect of your question. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Nice one mate, I was just doing that myself. I'll give you the upvote instead of posting a similar answer ;-)

Comment: @MartinLiversage THANK YOU SO MUCH !  It went a little above my skillz I guess, I had been fooling around in other ways for the past 3 days, so this really helped me ! THANK YOU !